# OmniAuth to extract full profile data from LinkedIn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, oauth, omniauth

I'm loving the ease of OmniAuth, but I'm having a hard time connecting the dots on making additional api calls after I receive the token back.

I'll use LinkedIn as an example, but it's not LinkedIn that's the issue, more so my lack of  understanding on how to make subsequent calls after I have authenticated.

I can make the request to LinkedIn and authenticate just fine.
Then I get the hash back and it's completely populated.

Now I would like to call LinkedIn back and get my complete profile data or maybe a list of contacts. How do I do this? Will I need the oauth gem after all?

I'd prefer to avoid app specific gems because I will have to make the same requests to twitter and facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Omniauth is designed for authentification only.

Comment: Please see my comment on Arkan's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Marcel Falliere is right. Omniauth is just for authentication.

You can have a look at this plugin, it could solve your problem.

https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin

Comment: Right, but how can we use OmniAuth to grab the config details, user tokens and whatever else is needed to make the request? Some suggestions show session[:omniauth][:token] or similar, but what if somebody is logged into a user account that has twitter, facebook, etc also attached?

Comment: You're right. It will be necessary to get valid tokens for each services required. I don't have the answer. Does anybody know ?

Comment: maybe the infos provided in this thread will help you out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187178/omniauth-pulling-tweets-fb-places-etc

Comment: I have this same issue and I'm not getting any traction. Everyone seems to be saying that it's just for auth and you can't actually make requests to the services. This seems incomplete to me. OmniAuth::Strategy has a request method (intridea.github.com/omniauth/OmniAuth/…) that seems like what you'd use, but I'm not sure how to get an instance of the strategy I'm using.

Comment: Well, it's called OmniAuth for a reason.
And you can pull an instance by doing `request.env["omniauth.strategy"]`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I just found out the answer to it.

after completion of oauth process with service provider(fb, twitter) omniauth saves the user. here it passes a hash to the user object and the content of hash are here https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Auth-Hash-Schema these credentials part can be used to request further request( infact u will have to save these in your user object).