# How do I use the access token in omniauth for Facebook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, oauth, omniauth, oauth-ruby

I have set this in the initializer

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :facebook , 'app' , 'secret' , {:scope => "manage_pages"}
end
```

And I have saved the token in User model after the callback.

How do I use the token to request for `https://graph.facebook.com/${current_user.uid}/accounts`?

Comment: I don't know about facebook, but maybe look around this thread maybe the infos provided in this thread will help you out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187178/omniauth-pulling-tweets-fb-places-etc

Comment: I have tried that but it is not working for facebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Facebook ID you can query the Facebook Graph. Have a look at fb_graph gem: https://github.com/nov/fb_graph, it is a Facebook API wrapper.