# How to fix omniauth error with yelp api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, gemfile

I am attempting to use the Yelp API in my Rails app but am having trouble doing so.  I'm following the documentation here (https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/blob/master/v2/ruby/example.rb) but keep getting an error.  Below is the code I'm using in the controller:

```
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'oauth'

    consumer_key = 'private'
    consumer_secret = 'private'
    token = 'private'
    token_secret = 'private-private'

    api_host = 'api.yelp.com'
    @places = Place.all
    consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(consumer_key, consumer_secret, {:site => "http://#{api_host}"})
    access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.new(consumer, token, token_secret)
    path = "/v2/search?term=restaurants&location=new%20york"
    p access_token.get(path).body
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
cannot load such file -- oauth
```

I have gem 'omniauth' in my Gemfile and have run bundle install (as well as restarted the server) but still get this error...any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
gem 'dynamic_form', '1.1.4'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'devise', '2.1.0rc'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'httparty'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :test, :development do
    gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.11'
end

group :test do
    gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the [omniauth documentation](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth#readme), you should be requiring 'omniauth', not 'oauth'

Comment: When I do this, I get an error saying uninitialized constant PlacesController::OAuth.  It seems the Yelp API is dated (2 years old) and still says OAuth instead of Omniauth.  How would I fix this?

Comment: right, because the guide you are looking at is for a different gem with a different API (API here meaning 'set of gem classes and methods etc.', NOT the yelp API - the yelp API doesn't care what gem you are using, their example is just old).  You need to read the omniauth documentation I linked to above for how to make an API call with the omniauth gem which is somewhat beyond the scope of this question and has been answered [elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675029/how-to-use-omniauth-to-make-authenticated-calls-to-services).

Comment: Here is an omniauth strategy for Yelp API.It needs some more testing though,Browse through the source code and that may help you.               https://github.com/dhaneshnm/omniauth-yelp/.

Answer (score -1):

You should run:

```
sudo gem install oauth
```

Or add gem `oauth` in the Gemfile.